# Rails controller method not getting called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have this button on a **page**:

```
<%= link_to 'Approve', {:action => "approve", :controller => "daily_balance_reconciliations", :method => :get}, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

I have defined this in **routes.rb**:

```
get "/daily_balance_reconciliations/approve" => "daily_balance_reconciliations#approve", :as => :approve_daily_balance_reconciliations
```

I have this method defined in **daily_balance_reconciliations_controller.rb**:

```
  def approve
puts "*************************approve*********************************"
@daily_balance_reconciliation = DailyBalanceReconciliation.all

DailyBalanceReconciliation.all.update_all(approved: true)    

redirect_to daily_balance_reconciliations_url, notice: "All the Daily Balance Records are approved"
end
```

The above method in my controller never gets called; the message inside puts statement never gets printed on my console.

What am I doing wrong here? Please help!

Comment: Try to use `<%= link_to 'Approve', approve_daily_balance_reconciliations_path, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>`

Comment: @mayur shah - I tried that first. That didn't work either

Comment: Do it one thing, run `rake routes` and try to find this route on command result.

Comment: @MayurShah _ I ran rake routes. This is what I got:        
     approve_daily_balance_reconciliations GET      /daily_balance_reconciliations/approve(.:format)             daily_balance_reconciliations#approve

Comment: You should NOT use a GET route here in the first place. GET should be idempotent - it should not create or alter any resources. GET requests are stored in the browser history! Use POST, PATCH or PUT. http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/idempotency/

Comment: @max - I used POST as you suggested. But I don't see any update query being fired in the console. 1. What am I missing to run an UPDATE query? 2. Also, I see this on the console - `Processing by DailyBalanceReconciliationsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"method"=>"post", "id"=>"approve"}
`. Why does id=>approve appear. is that correct?

Comment: No that does not look correct. You have an another route in `routes.rb` that that is taking precedence. Routes have priority in the order they are defined.